# How do I create two different backgrounds on the same page?

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

Can anyone tell me how to create the background as shown on this website:
www.zucoffee.com

Also, how can I get that curved separation? I realize they're two divs, but how was the border curved?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: That said, it seems like you haven't tried anything. Have you inspected the element with the browser's developer tool? maybe inspect the css? hint: it's a background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the curved separation comes from the fact that the header image has purple in the bottom to create the curve. the actual file can be seen here: http://www.zucoffee.com/wp-content/themes/zu-coffee/images/header-bg.gif

This (to my knowledge) is fairly common practice to have one background that serves the entire page, and have another separate background on top of that which serves just the header and/or footer. depending on the style of the site, this may include interesting separations, and I have also seen .pngs used to get the header/footer design to 'fade' into the main background.

There are obviously many different ways that you can do this, and I'm sure someone will want to add on to my answer, but the way your example site chose was to use the `background` property on their body and header tags to add their images. a snippet from their css file below:

```
body { 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
  background:#4b1259 url(images/tile-bg.gif) repeat-x;
  width:100%;
  display:table;
  font:16px/22px Georgia;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align:left; 
}
.header-bg { //this is where i found them adding the header image.
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background:url(images/header-bg.gif) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Divs are block level elements and are as such block shaped (square/rectangular).

If you inspect the element header-bg on the page in question using Chromes Developer tools or Firebug in Firefox you can see that the it uses css to set a background image with a curved lower edge. Image is header-bg.gif.